# jQuery Ajax sending Object to PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

**before JSON.stringify**

```
[Object { key="name", val="John Doe"}, Object { key="email", val="doe@doe.com"}, Object { key="company", val="JOHN INC"}, Object { key="tel", val="01234"}, Object { key="subject", val="Sales Enquiry"}, Object { key="comments", val="HELLOOO"}]
```

**JSON.stringify**

```
[{"key":"name","val":"John Doe"},{"key":"email","val":"doe@doe.com"},{"key":"company","val":"JOHN DOE INC"},{"key":"tel","val":"01345"},{"key":"subject","val":"Sales Enquiry"},{"key":"comments","val":"HELLOOO"}]
```

The above is what is output using the `console.log(strung)` in the code below. What I'm trying to get is the data to send via ajax to PHP so that I can then use for example `$_POST['name']` in the PHP to send an email.

```
var strung = JSON.stringify(arr);
    console.log(arr);
console.log(strung);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/contact.php",
    data: strung,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you change how `arr` is built? Its quite verbose.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var param = {};

$.each(arr, function() {
    param[this.key] = this.val;
});
```

And send

```
data: param,
```

in the $.ajax parameter.

You can access in PHP,

```
echo $_POST['name'], $_POST['email']
```

...